# Why multiple ObjectMapper instaces creation doesn't take much time?

Tags: java, jackson

I perform a simple test - I create several ObjectMapper objects in a row. I do that because I'm trying to understand the cost of it. There are a lot of resources saying ObjectMapper is thread-safe and creation of it is heavy. So what I'm expecting to see is each ObjectMapper creation would take some time. But when I go through the lines in Eclipse Debugger I see that only the first creation of the ObjectMapper takes some time. Could anybody explain why? Is it some compiler optimisation? Or am i missing something?
Here is my test:

```
    String inputString = "{\"key1\":\"value1\"}";
    String inputString2 = "{\"key2\":\"value2\"}";
    String inputString3 = "{\"key3\":\"value3\"}";
    String inputString4 = "{\"key4\":\"value4\"}";

    try {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString, HashMap.class);
        HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString2, HashMap.class);
        HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString3, HashMap.class);
        HashMap<String, Object> map4 = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputString4, HashMap.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where are your measurements? Besides, doing any kind of time related benchmarks using debugger is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at initialization of `ObjectMapper` instances and can verify the described behavior:

```
StopWatch '': running time = 2323937394 ns
---------------------------------------------
ns         %     Task name
---------------------------------------------
2233845422  096 %  map1
030696401  001 %  map2
029092790  001 %  map3
030302781  001 %  map4
```

The reason seems to be the initialization of static blocks and static member fields of the `ObjectMapper` instance which is only run when the class is loaded for the first time.

Prior to the execution of the `ObjectMapper` constructor the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>()` static initializer is executed, which sets all the static fields of the `ObjectMapper`instance like `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.BaseSettings.<clinit>()` etc.

Thereafter, when the `ObjectMapper`constructor is run for the first time, all the static fields and static blocks of its non-static members are initialized e.g `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.<clinit>()` which takes an additional amount of time. These static initialization steps are only run when the construction is executed for the first time.